# Use of lpNorm in Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen

I am trying to do some L_p norm calculations within a template function something of the sort

```
template<typename Number>
Number foo(const Eigen::MatrixBase<Number>& matrix)
{
  return matrix.lpNorm<1>(); 
}
```

However, CLang throws an error "expected expression" at the end of the line if I try to call `foo(matrix)`. If I work with concretely defined (double) matrices, `lpNorm` works just fine. How do I go about with this case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Classical C++ mistake. The solution is to use the `template` keyword as follow:

```
return matrix.template lpNorm<1>();
```

See the [details](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicTemplateKeyword.html).

Comment: Me neither! Discovering new stuffs in C++ every day!